# Create refresh functionality on python dash button click

Tags: python-3.x, dashboard

I created one dash, with some UI component. There is one submit button which will get all data from dash UI and store into database. Everything is working perfectly.

Now i want to refresh/reload the page on submit button click. So submit button will perform it's operation and after storing data into database, page will reload. 
Is dash API has any function to reload page?